# How to identify and switch to the frame in selenium webdriver when frame does not have id and title?

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone tell me how I can identify and switch to the iframe which hasn't title and id. Part of the iframe (i have two iframe with same attributes):

```
<iframe style="width: 1335px; height: 223px;" src="javascript:true;" frameborder="0">
<html>
#document
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
</html>
</html>
</iframe>
```

How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java? 
Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Use frame index `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` , it starts from ZERO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the solutions below.

If necessary try to switch to default content before you access web-elements from iframe. So include below code before the code to detect the iframe.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

Comment: Thakns a lot.

  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(0));

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one iframe element in your DOM then using tag makes sense.

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
```

or you can switch to it directly without even finding it -

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

If there are multiple iframes but with different attributes, then you can use attributes to get the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@frameborder='0']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='javascript:true;']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[style='width: 1335px; height: 223px;']"));
```

If there are multiple iframes with same attributes then using other element to locate your iframe would work. [Here's an example using xpath](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/06/xpath-tutorials-identifying-xpath-for.html). Later once you find the element you can `switchTo()` it. Hope this helps.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe[style='width: 1335px;']"}

Comment: Part of the iframe (i have two iframe with same attributes):

<iframe style="width: 1335px; height: 223px;" src="javascript:true;" frameborder="0"><html>#document<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head></head></html></html></iframe>

Comment: Sorry my bad. Updated code  for cssSelector. If you same iframe with same attributes, use xpath method to identify it. If you can post your html code of other iframe with relevant to the current one, then probably i can help you out with that. Also is there any unique element near one of these iframes?

Answer (score 0):

if there is only one or if it is first iframe, you can do that:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: 0

but i have two iframe

Answer (score -1):

This might be the dumbest way of doing it and I don't know if its what you are looking for.

If its a frame you can right click on the field and you will see the choice of "open frame in a tab".

Then take the URL of the frame and put it in your Python script using "driver.get (http://blah blah..)

Then Selenium can find your named element.

I'm using Linux which gives me the right-click option of opening the frame, on its own, in another tab. I don't use Windows so don't know if you would get that option in you right-click menu.

Ganz